# How can I delete blob files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am creating an image viewer using XMLHttpRequest. It includes this function:

```
        public view_image(_tImagen: iConfigImagen){
        var img_view = this.prop_div_vizualizador;

        var _window: any = window;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", _tImagen.url, true);
            xhr.responseType = "blob";
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var urlCreator = _window.URL = _window.URL || _window.webkitURL;
                var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
                _tImagen.urlBlob = imageUrl;
                img_view.style("background-image", "url(" + _tImagen.urlBlob + ")");
            }
    }
```

It works fine, but I am trying to delete the blob files that it generates somehow. I tried `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)`, but that only deletes the url and not the file. How can I delete the files? Is there any way to remove them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the files on the disk? That's not possible using JS.

Comment: Yes, they are only deleted when I refresh the page. So there is no way to eliminate them?

Answer (score 1):

The XMLHttpRequest allows you to make an HTTP request and receive a response, but it does not give you access to the file system. You cannot delete files without access to them.